# ColdFusion Session Variables

Tags: session, coldfusion

Do the session variables in coldfusion expire or purge before the specified limit? Like say if the expiration is set to 24 hours, and the user only interacts with them for 10 minutes, do they expire if there not being used before the 24 hours?

Comment: 24 hours seems like an unreasonably long time for Session variables. I wouldn't go over an hour.

Comment: Remember as well that whatever you set the limit for session variables in the application, it won't go longer than the CF admin setting for Session variables. If CF Admin sets the limit to 20 minutes that will be the maximum for your application.

Comment: @Al maximum session timeout setting in the ColdFusion Administrator is a very important point, which I didn't list in my answer. I also agree, that setting the timeout to 24 hours wouldn't be recommended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually not. Given, you set a time-out of 24 hours for your session variables and you would log in for the first time, doing stuff for 10 minutes then your session is active for 24 hours after the last mouseclick. Unless you restart the server, or client deletes cookies, or your purge interval (Purge data for clients that remain unvisited for ...) in ColdFusion Administrator is less than your session time-out.

Comment: Note that if you're using J2EE session variables, that links to a non-persistent cookie. If the user closes their browser they have essentially "lost" the connection to their session variables.